# Rowspan with iTextSharp doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, itext, html-table

I'm trying to create a simple table with iTextSharp, so with C#. The goal is a table like this one:

[image]

The problem is that if I apply the rowspan as 2 on cell A, iTextSharp does not render the rowspanned cell, this means that the cell have the same height of cell B. Here's the code:

```
    PdfPTable corporateTable = new PdfPTable(2);
    corporateTable.HeaderRows = 1;
    corporateTable.TotalWidth = pdfWidth - 50;

    PdfPCell vCell = new PdfPCell();
    vCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
    vCell.Rowspan = 2;
    vCell.Phrase = new Phrase("A", new Font(fontLh, 7f, 1, BaseColor.BLACK));
    corporateTable.CompleteRow();
    corporateTable.AddCell(vCell);


    PdfPCell vCellx = new PdfPCell();
    vCellx.Phrase = new Phrase("B", new Font(fontLh, 7f, 1, BaseColor.BLACK));
    vCellx.Colspan = 3;
    corporateTable.AddCell(vCellx);

    PdfPCell vCell1 = new PdfPCell();
    vCell1.Phrase = new Phrase("C", new Font(fontValue, 7f, 0, BaseColor.BLACK));
    corporateTable.AddCell(vCell1);

    corporateTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 100f, 100f, writer.DirectContent);
    document.Close();
```

What's wrong? I'm using the latest version of the dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the basic answer is: it  works! if you add two more cells, you will see that one cell (the one underneath A) is not filled.

But this is not what you expect (nor did I btw). To achive what you want use nested tables, that means:

- create a table with two cols
- insert cell A into table
- create cell 2
- create one more table with 1 col

  - insert cell B into table 2
  - insert cell c into table 2
- insert table 2 into cell 2

search for itext rowspan, you will find multiple fully typed out examples.

hth

Mario

Comment: Ok but this means that iTextSharp works differently from html, so I cannot do this without nesting the tables?

Comment: This is what I found, yes. I played arround with your code as well, and the rowspan works, just the aligment is not justified as to be between the rows. I may check my iText in Action book somewhen tonite (MESZ). regards

Comment: BTW: if you find the answer helpful, an upvote would be nice :-)

Comment: Well I noticed that if I stroke the table using 'document.Add(corporateTable);' instead of 'corporateTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, -1, 300f, 100f, writer.DirectContent);' the rowspanned cell appears!

Comment: is it now aligned between the two other rows? I used Add as well, and it was not aligned.

Comment: Yes, if I use both "Add" and "writeselectedrows" there are 2 tables, one aligned on top and the other one is aligned as I put it (300,100). the problem concern also the size of table, the first one does not have the width I set :(

Comment: tables are a tad beasty with iText (or pdf..). I will look up the examples in the book later on and post here.

Comment: I checked his book, and also he is solving it using a nested table. The only time Iowagie himself uses rowspan is with the PdfTable class. For an example of nested table see: http://www.1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=106 . hth

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work. Try to remove following code rows:

```
corporateTable.CompleteRow();
...
vCellx.Colspan = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at

```
vCellx.Colspan = 3;
```

Use

```
vCellx.Colspan = 1;
```

because you declared pdf table with two columns. You already added one column with rowspan 3 so you have only another one column and not three columns